# how do I get subscriber information, base on the subscriber ID?

Tags: magento2, newsletter-subscriber

how do I get subscriber information, base on the subscriber ID?
I would like to grab their email address, name ...etc by the subscriber ID. or even their customer ID

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check below code

Create Block

> **File**:-app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Block/SubscribeMagento.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright DeviMage
 *
 * @see PROJECT_LICENSE.txt
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;

/**
 * Class SubscribeMagento
 */
class SubscribeMagento extends Template
{
     /**
     * @var SubscriberFactory
     */
    private $subscriberFactory;

    /**
     * SubscribeMagento constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
    }


    public function getSubscribeDataById() {

        $ID = 7;
         try {
                $collection = $this->subscriberFactory->create()->getCollection()
                           ->addFieldToFilter('subscriber_id', $ID);
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
                return null;
        }

        return $collection;
    }


}
```

Then print on template **Customtemplate.phtml**

```
echo '<PRE>';
print_r($block->getSubscribeDataById()->getData());
```

If directly using object manager to get subscribe data then check below code

> **Object Manger**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$subscribeCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber');
/** Apply filters here */
$ID = 7;
$collection = $subscribeCollection->getCollection()
                                  ->addFieldToFilter('subscriber_id', $ID);

foreach ($collection as $subscribe){
     echo 'Email  =  '.$subscribe->getSubscriberEmail().'<br>';
     echo 'CustomerId  =  '.$subscribe->getCustomerId().'<br>';
     echo 'SubscriberStatus  =  '.$subscribe->getSubscriberStatus().'<br>';
}
```

Then hit below commands

```
sudo rm -rf var/* generated/* pub/static/frontend/*
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```

I hope this will help you..!

Comment: if you have to get data using customer id then get  customer id and set ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', 15);

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful! I would like to use above code inside the /vendor/magento/module-newsletter/controller/subscriber/confirm.php (I will override the module if it works), the reason I do this, it is because I want when click the confirmation link inside the email and will trigger above and I will have a API call to other system by POST method.

Comment: ok check it and let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Can I just implement your above to  /vendor/magento/module-newsletter/controller/subscriber/confirm.php ? I did try to insert Object manger method, I can't echo out the result to the log.

Comment: yes, you can use above code in confirm.php file.

Comment: its work great! I can grab the info I need, Thanks for your help!

Comment: Most Welcome @PaulFan